# webpack - exclude files from specific entry point

Tags: javascript, webpack

In my application I have multiple entry points.
One entry point is creating a bundle which is restricted only for signed in users.

Is there a way to tell webpack to not bundle any file that needs to be restricted into the 'public' bundle? and instead not bundle it / throw a compilation error?

is there an exclude per entry point?

The only solution I can think of is creating two separate webpack config files, is there a better way?

Thanks

--- edit ---

I will try to rephrase the question -
Is there a way to enforce that some files will be excluded from a specific bundle/entry point, or in other words, there are files that I want in a specific bundle, and not in a any other bundle, and I want to enforce it.

Comment: just don't require/import that file anywhere in your files, this way webpack will never bundle it

Comment: Yea, but I'm looking for a way to enforce it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Webpack documentation link :
[Exclude File](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition) and [Multiple Configurations](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-multiple-configurations)

```
module.exports = [{
      output: {
        filename: './dist-amd.js',
        libraryTarget: 'amd'
      },
      name: 'amd',
      entry: './app.js',
      mode: 'production',
      rules: [
              {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [
                    'src/configs/configs/your1.js'
                  ]
              }
            ]
    }, {
      output: {
        filename: './dist-commonjs.js',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs'
      },
      name: 'commonjs',
      entry: './app2.js',
      mode: 'production', 
      rules: [
              {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [
                    'src/configs/configs/your2.js'
                  ]
              }
            ]
    }];

  };
```

Special thanks to @Axnyff for completing my answer.

Comment: thanks, but I want it per entry, and I think this rule applies to all entries

Comment: @naortor could this be solved using Goldy's solution and a multiple compiler, meaning you export two config instead of having multiple entries: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-multiple-configurations

Comment: @Axnyff thanks, I think this is what I was looking for, if you will write it as an answer I will accept it (as I said in the question, I was already familiar with the exclude option, was looking for a solution of making it per entry)